# Detect all injection points in Java (Guice) via static code analysis

Tags: java, java-8, guice, static-analysis

I'm working on a large scale project in Java that uses Guice as its dependency injection framework.
Is it possible to find **all places** in that code that a specific object type should be injected to?
*Clarification:* via static code analysis, not during runtime.

Specifically, I have a method that is annotated `@Provides`.
I want to detect **all places** in the code that are bounded to this method return value.

#### Update:

According to [this](https://justin.abrah.ms/misc/an-overview-of-guice-java-dependency-injection.html), there isn't any existing tool for this job.

> There isn't any static analysis of Guice to see if you actually have bindings for the annotations you said you did. This means that failures in Guice happen at run-time. Given that developers can fat-finger strings not referenced as constants, Guice also allows you to use your own annotations.

Comment: Do you want to know this know, one time, by analysing the .java files on your machine or do you want to know it at runtime to base some logic on?

Comment: @luk2302 Static analysis

Comment: Check IntelliJ's source code. In IntelliJ, injection points are linked to definition when using Guice. So they very likely have a static analysis tool.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this search yielded no results.

Answer (score -1):

*Caveat:* This solution is hardly complete nor robust (as is also mentioned in the comments), but it might be sufficient in the absence of a better solution.

The simple solution I have found for this is using a regular expression.
For example, if the "provider" method returns a class `Foo`, then the expression should be:

```
@Inject[\s\S]+?\W(Foo)
```

This does not cover, for example, nested injection patterns, such as parameters for methods annotated with `@Provides`.

Comment: "**All places**"? This regex doesn't come even close to "**all places**". You should check for other `@Provides` (and friends) method, Example: `@Provides Foo provideFoo() { return ...; } @Provides Bar provideBar(Foo foo) { return ...; }` And that's just the first I'm thinking about right now. Also, you totally disregard qualifiers. If there's no qualifier on your provider, but there's one on your IP, the IP will be matched, but Guice will not match those.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I wasn't aware of this functionality in Guice. This is why I was wondering if there is a "real" solution to this problem.
It seems feasible that such option will be available, and yet there is no other answer in this thread.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Since a partial solution is better than no solution, I don't see a reason for the downvote.

Comment: In the question that *you* wrote, *you* emphasized on "**all places**". Twice. Your own answer isn't even close to "all places" by a mile. So this is definitely a bad answer for the question.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I agree it is not a good enough by my own requirements. But I still think that other users can benefit from this solution. Especially since the caveats are clear and mentioned in this answer. I myself reserve downvotes for misleading answers that the authors themselves do not understand the question or even their own answer.